# How do i make domain parking on my website without accessing or adding them to my Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, dns, nameservers

i think of creating a website like wapka,Xtgem,Mywapblog etc and i know the scope of writing this where user can have domain like 
myblog.ownwebsite.com
or 
stackoverflow.freeblog.com

but this names did not look nice , if use want to buy domain like stackoverflowblog.com  and park it to my website without having access to my cpanel so if they access stackoverflowblog.com it will show contents of stackoverflow.freeblog.com .
and how i can set my IP address to Map to my coded website 
eg   129.456.768.8 => ns1.freeblog.com 
     129.456.768.9 => ns2.freeblog.com

i think of how they develop the website but i couldn't get it please can anyone assist me on this???

i use PHP and MYSQL thou,

thanks.

Comment: please use propperr code formatting... not easy to ready what you typed

Comment: You have not shown what you have tried for the PHP backend. Anyway, it is a bad idea to send a HTTP request just to refresh the page and get some words appended into your textarea. It is definitely a much better solution to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: i just Update the question to another question , please can annyone help me?